# ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT - How to insert values?

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-insert, auto-increment

I created an SQLite table in Java:

```
create table participants (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, col1,col2);
```

I tried to add rows :

```
insert into participants values ("bla","blub");
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: table participants has 3 columns but 2 values
> were supplied

I thought `ROWID` would be generated automatically. I tried another solution:

```
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into participants values (?,?,?);");
Integer n = null;
prep.setInt(1,n);
prep.setString(2, "bla");
prep.setString(3, "blub");
prep.addBatch();
prep.executeBatch();
```

I received a null pointer exception at `prep.setInt(1,n);`. Do you see the fault?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Have you tried indicating to which fields of the table the parameters you are passing are supposed to be related?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

In your case maybe something like:

```
INSERT INTO participants(col1, col2) VALUES ("bla","blub");
```

Comment: If you're doing a schema migration and using a select statement for your insertion you can do `insert into participants(col1, col2) select col1, col2 from t1_backup;`

Answer (score 34):

Easiest way without using column names will be [using null](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) in the place of [autoincreament](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is like this

```
insert into table values (null, col1, col2)
```

if you have already set the first column as autoincrement, it will work fine.

Answer (score 9):

found a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631060/can-i-make-a-field-autoincrement-after-made-a-table):

```
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into participants values ($next_id,?,?);");
prep.setString(2, "bla");
prep.setString(3, "blub");
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason to your error is that SQL Inserts expect you to provide the same number of values as there are columns in the table when a column specifier is not used.

i.e. when you write a SQL query like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES(a1,a2, ...)
```

.. the values have to be in the exact same order as in the table definition (and also the same amount). The reason for this is to avoid ambiguity and reduce the numbers of errors.

In your case you have an auto increment column which you don't want to specify a value for. That is of course possible, but following the rules above you need to specify column names:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (columnName1, columnName2) VALUES(Value1, Value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create **"person" table** with **"id"** with **AUTOINCREMENT** and **"name"** as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (    -- Here
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT
);
```

Then, set **NULL** to **"id"** of **AUTOINCREMENT** as shown below. *You can set **NULL** to **"id"** which has **NOT NULL** because **"id"** has **[INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)**:

```sql
INSERT INTO person VALUES (NULL, "John"), (NULL, "Tom");
```

Now, you can insert rows as shown below:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬──────┐
│ id │ name │
├────┼──────┤
│ 1  │ John │
│ 2  │ Tom  │
└────┴──────┘
```