# SQLite executemany asking for more values than expected

Tags: python, sqlite, auto-increment, executemany

I'm trying to insert a list into a database with SQLite, the first value is an id with `AUTOINCREMENT` property. This is the code:

```
# cursor.execute('''
#    CREATE TABLE products (
#        prod_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
#        prod_name VARCHAR(20),
#        prod_brand VARCHAR(20),
#        price FLOAT
#    )
# ''')

products = [
    ('Keyboard', 'Doctor Key', 20.0),
    ('Mouse', 'MasterClick', 2.50)
]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO products VALUES (null,?,?,?), products")
```

I also tried doing this:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO products (prod_id,prod_name,prod_brand,price) VALUES (null,?,?,?),productos")
```

But in both cases I got the same error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "leccion2-1.py", line 38, in <module>
            cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO products VALUES (null,?,?,?), products") 
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250814/sqlite-autoincrement-how-to-insert-values) did not worked for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the values outside of your quotes, since you are passing a variable, not a string.

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO products VALUES (null,?,?,?)", products)
```

See also this [example](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/sqlite3.Cursor.executemany):

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("samples.db")
cur = con.cursor()

examples = [(2, "def"), (3, "ghi"), (4, "jkl")]
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO samples VALUES (?, ?)", examples)

for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM samples"):
    print row
```